# Убрать дублирующиеся слэши в середине url средствами mod_rewrite

Tags: регулярные-выражения, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Нужно убрать лишние слэши в ссылках вида:

```
http://site.ru////page
http://site.ru////page////catalog
http://site.ru////page////
```

c последним справляется

```
RewriteRule (.+)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

А как быть с остальными?

Пытался использовать то, что предлагалось в похожих темах, но никак не реагирует

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)//(.*)$
RewriteRule . %1/%2 [R=301,L]
```

**UPD**

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.*?)/{2,}([^\s]*)
RewriteRule ^ %1/%2 [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteRule (.+)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

разбирает всё кроме

```
http://site.ru////
```

как быть?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы решаете проблему не с того конца. Начнём с ключевого вопроса: **откуда такие ссылки берутся?**

Если источник "некрасивых" ссылок — ваш сайт, то в первую очередь нужно исправить ваш сайт.

Если источник "некрасивых" ссылок — другие сайты, то их должно быть пренебрежимо мало. Большинство людей будет при ссылке на ваш сайт использовать адреса, которые выдаёт ваш сайт, а не выдумывать что-то самостоятельно и расставлять слэши от балды.

Для поиска источников ссылок можете воспользоваться разнообразными средствами аналитики: Google Webmaster, Google Analytics, Яндекс.Вебмастер, Яндекс.Метрика и др.

---

Теперь, когда **источника** ссылок больше нет, может оказаться, что поисковики всё ещё используют "некрасивые" ссылки. Если вас это беспокоит, то указывайте на каждой странице канонический адрес.

Для этого вы можете воспользоваться `<link rel='canonical'>`, картами сайта, редиректами и т.п. В большинстве случаев поисковики справляются с обнаружением дулблированного контента на сайте и воспринимают дубли как одну страницу, а из доступных URLов выбирают самый "красивый", поэтому можете не заморачиваться.

См. [Use canonical URLs](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066?hl=en) ([Канонические URL](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066?hl=ru)).

---

`.htaccess` — это сложный и неудобный инструмент. В него можно внести несколько правил, но, чем сложнее правила, тем менее читаемым становится код. Если вы упираетесь в возможности `.htaccess`, то перенесите весь роутинг в скрипты и не мучайтесь.

Comment: добавлю еще, что данную задачу в общем виде нельзя решить с помощью .htaccess. Лучшим решением будет добавить правило, которое найдя два слэша подряд направляет на страницу-роутер. Роутер исправляет адрес и делает на него редирект.

Comment: Я это понимаю. И нигде нет ссылок на мой сайт вида http://site.ru////page////catalog. Но, в тоже время, мне хочется, чтобы пользователь или машина, перейдя по такой ссылке, попали на нужную страницу, а не на 404 ошибку. Проблему решил. Код htaccess добавлен в пост в конце. А для ссылок вида http://site.ru//// решил на уровне php скрипта, который интерпретирует данный адрес как просто запрос на index.php.

Answer (score -1):

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} //

RewriteRule .* /$0 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Уверен, автор вопроса был бы благодарен за ваш экспертный комментарий к приведенному выше коду.