# Битрикс. Не работает 301 редирект в композитном режиме

Tags: php, битрикс

На сайте нужно реализовать редирект с url в котором может быть произвольное количество слэшей **http://site.ru/dir////dir///dir///////** на **http://site.ru/dir/dir/dir/**

Сайт работает в композитном режиме. Что пробовал сделать.

В init.php добавлял следующий код:

```
<?
$isHttps = !empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && 'off' !== strtolower($_SERVER['HTTPS']);
$protocol = "http";

if($isHttps){
    $protocol = "https";
}

if(strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],"/bitrix/admin/") === false){


    $RequestUri = explode("?",$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

    $RequestNoParam = $RequestUri[0];
    $RequestParam = $RequestUri[1];

    // 1
    // Делаем редирект на url в нижнем регистре

    if ($RequestNoParam != strtolower($RequestNoParam) ) {

        if(!empty($RequestParam)){
            $RedirectUri = $protocol . '://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . strtolower($RequestNoParam) . '?' . $RequestParam;
        }else{
            $RedirectUri = $protocol . '://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . strtolower($RequestNoParam);
        }



        header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
        header('Location:' .$RedirectUri);
        exit();
    }

    // 2
    // Делаем редирект , если в url более 2-х раз повторяется "/"

    $countSlashReplace = 0;
    $RequestNoMultiSlash = preg_replace('~//+~',"/",$RequestNoParam,-1,$countSlashReplace);

    if($countSlashReplace){


        if(!empty($RequestParam)){
            $RedirectUri = $protocol . '://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . strtolower($RequestNoMultiSlash) . '?' . $RequestParam;
        }else{
            $RedirectUri = $protocol . '://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . strtolower($RequestNoMultiSlash);
        }

        header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
        header('Location:' .$RedirectUri);

        exit();
    }
}
```

В первом условии, редирект работает отлично. 
Но когда делаем проверку на слэши, то в композитном режиме это условие не работает. Если выключить композит то, оба условия прекрасно работают.

Из документации по Битриксу, понял, что вырубить композит можно **кукой NCC** или добавить к url GET **параметр ncc**

Что я пробовал, в **.htaccess** с помощью директивы php_value auto_prepend_file "**/var/www/path_to_site_dir/bitrix/php_interface/include/auto_prepend_file.php**"

В нем разместил следующий код:

```
$RequestUri = explode("?",$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

        $RequestNoParam = $RequestUri[0];
        $RequestParam = $RequestUri[1];

        if ($RequestNoParam != strtolower($RequestNoParam) ) {

            $_GET['ncc'] = '';
        }


        $countSlashReplace = 0;
        $RequestNoMultiSlash = preg_replace('~//+~',"/",$RequestNoParam,-1,$countSlashReplace);

        if($countSlashReplace){

            $_GET['ncc'] = '';

        }
```

композит отключается , но редиректа все равно не происходит, вопрос, какой еще может быть нюанс ? что я мог упустить ? буду рад любым рекомендациям.

В .htaccess пробовал:

```
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)//(.*)$
#RewriteRule . %1/%2 [R,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} //
RewriteRule ^.*$ $0 [R=302,L,NE]

#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} //+
#RewriteRule ^(.*) $1 [R=301,L] 

#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)/{2,}(.*)$
#RewriteRule . %1/%2 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Честно говоря я не знаю что такое композитный режим, а htaccess нельзя сделать?

Comment: Если кратко то, суть композита в том, что страница разбивается на статичные и динамичные области, т.е если данные на странице никак не менялись то отдается html кеш страницы, а если есть изменения, то данные подгружаются только для выбранных динамичных областей.  Если подробнее то можно прочитать тут https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/learning/course/index.php?COURSE_ID=39&LESSON_ID=4887&LESSON_PATH=3910.4887

Comment: в htacсess. пробовал, нечего не выходит.

Comment: И все же. Правильное решение - использовать modrewite в htaccess. Извраты с php это костыль.  тем более до вашего условия начинает работать urlrewrite. Композит, здесь лишь косвенно, я думаю, какой-то косяк от нестандартности ситуации вылезает. Т.к. копозит, по сути,  это обычная загрузка страницы из кеша +  на аяксе обновляются некоторые области. Из всех правил htaccess на мой взгляд последнее самое правильное. Но надо пробовать

Comment: Хотя нет.  Оно не правильное. Оно не заменяет несколько сллешей на один. СОвсем

Comment: Еще "мысль". А откуда у вас такие ссылки?

Comment: Вот здесь есть похожий вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/416021/%D0%A3%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%83%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%8D%D1%88%D0%B8-%D0%B2-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5-url-%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-mod-rewrite

Comment: вообщем проблема решилась, html отдавал nginx , и из за того что по умолчанию в nginx включена настройка merge_slashes on, у меня не происходило редиректа.

Добавил решение в ответ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавил в конфиг nginx
в секцию

server:

```
merge_slashes off;
```

в location:

```
rewrite (.*)//+(.*)$1/$2/ permanent;
```

И 301 редирект заработал.